# Close vim window in terminal

Tags: vim, terminal

I am using vim within a terminal. Whenever I close vim (using :q), the windows stay in the buffer of the terminal. I can type commands, but I still see the text that I was editing. I don't know how to get rid of this behaviour.

Does anybody know what I can do to change this behaviour ? In my .vimrc / terminal configuration ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using for the terminal?

Comment: how about a ctrl+l after you quit?

Comment: I am using Terminal on mac os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `'restorescreen'` option must be set (it is by default, but something might have turned it off).

```
:verbose set restorescreen?
```

will tell you. What kind of escape sequences must be sent (and whether they are understood by your terminal, whose name you unfortunately didn't mention), depends on your terminal. Check out `:help 'restorescreen'` for hints (and maybe try with another terminal emulator).

Comment: Unfortunatly this solution seems to work on Windows 95/NT version. I am using Terminal on Mac OS. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Because it relies on ANSI escape sequences, this setting should work on all curses-based terminals, I think.